I need to upload to play store an app that targets API 33 but they require that API should be 34
I'm facing an issue with uploading my app to the Play Store. They're requesting that I update the target API to 34, but my app's factory reset functionality only works with API 33. When I change the target API to 34, the app uploads successfully, but the factory reset code stops functioning. If I keep the target API at 33, the factory reset works, but I cannot upload the app.
Is there a way to upload an app targeting API 33 to the Play Store?
Is there a way to make the factory reset code work on API 34, I am getting exception
java.lang.SecurityException: User 0 is a system user and cannot be removed


What is the code that is throwing the error? Just seeing the error code doesn't provide enough context for an answer

Google Play Store now requires that all apps target at least API level 34 (Android 14) to ensure compatibility with the latest system features and security updates. Therefore, targeting API level 33 is no longer acceptable for new app updates.
Regarding your issue with the factory reset functionality when targeting API level 34, the error you're encountering (java.lang.SecurityException: User 0 is a system user and cannot be removed) is related to stricter security measures in Android 14 that prevent certain sensitive operations, such as factory resets, from being performed programmatically, especially when the user is the system (primary) user.
Android 14 might have changed the security rules around factory resets, especially if you're using APIs like DevicePolicyManager to reset the device.
use alternative
Use Device Owner or Profile Owner : you need to get permission that your app have to be admin so you can achieve your task
In API level 34, for performing a factory reset, your app needs to be a device owner or profile owner, Ensure that your app is set up correctly as a device administrator.
Source from Android Documentation :  Click Here
Also check Permissions : Make sure your app has the correct permissions, including DEVICE_ADMIN and that it’s registered as the device admin using the DeviceAdminReceiver.
and for both use code like this :
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) { // API 34
    // Handle factory reset differently or show an error to users
} else {
    // Execute factory reset code for API 33 or lower
}


is there any solution for that?
